# Passing a $scope variable to a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am struggling to pass data from my model to a directive and have little to no idea how. I am an AngularJS newbie :).

My markup is as follows below. Currently witnessing two problems:

1) scope.$parent.companyName is always blank no matter what I type? I have declared an empty value because otherwise it's `undefined` and that seems like an anti-pattern.

2) Even if I get (1) working, it's relying on the layout of the model I give it because of $parent. How do I pass a string to the directive?

I have a view:

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-royal">
        <h1 class="title">{{ registerTitle }}</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
        <div class="list list-inset">
            <label>
                {{ registerInfoLabel }}
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="{{ companyNameLabel }}" ng-model="companyName">
            </label>
            <label>
                <button class="button button-block button-royal" register-app>
                    {{ registerLabel }}
                </button>
            </label>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

A controller:

```
angular.module('app')

    .controller('RegisterController', ['$scope', '$appI18n', function ($scope, $appI18n) {
        $scope.registerTitle = $appI18n.RegisterTitle;
        $scope.registerLabel = $appI18n.RegisterLabel;
        $scope.companyNameLabel = $appI18n.CompanyName;
        $scope.registerInfoLabel = $appI18n.RegisterInfoLabel;

        $scope.companyName = '';
    }]);
```

And a directive:

```
angular.module('app')

    .directive('registerApp', ['RegisterService', function (RegisterService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('click', function () {
                    alert(scope.$parent.companyName);
                })
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send a string in to the directive using an attribute.  If you only have one parameter to send then you can use the directive itself like this:

```
<div register-app="companyName"></div>
```

And adding it to your directive scope:

```
scope: { registerApp : '=' },
```

Then it'll be available on your scope:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log("cname ",scope.registerApp);
}
```

Here's an example of that working:  http://jsfiddle.net/kgwkf02c/

**Or** you could send it in using it's own attribute (especially useful if you want to send in multiple values):

```
<div register-app cname="companyName"></div>
```

With the directive looking like:

```
scope: { cname : '=' },
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          console.log("cname ",scope.cname);
}
```

Here's that version:  http://jsfiddle.net/kgwkf02c/1/

Comment: Thanks! Where can I get more information on the second segment of code? I have seen that syntax thrown around and never understood it (and it's not something you can easily Google :))

Comment: There's discussion the directive documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). In specific this is scope binding (or isolate scope).  But that's a lot to wade through.  Do you have any specific questions- I can probably point you to something more focused that way.

Comment: Thanks! I just wondered what the available values there are for the scope object? E.g. what the '=' means and the other ones (I think I've seen '@' too)?

Comment: There's some good, short videos I recommend.  Here's [one on using =](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-two-way-binding), [one on @](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-attribute-binding), [and on &](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-expression-binding).  Also, here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxisam/QrCXh/) that I found helpful which demos each.